# Error - Could not find handle.exe, please install from sysinternals

Tags: rabbitmq

I am installing rabbitmq on my windows machine and below are the versions I have installed
Erlang - erl-24.1.6
RabbitMq - 3.9.9

I am getting the following line getting logged every 10 mins. However everything seem to be working fine.

```
> [error] <0.474.0> Could not find handle.exe, please install from
> sysinternals
```

I have followed some articles and downloaded the handle and extracted that to C:\Program Files\Handle and added this path into my path variable.
[image]

I still see this error. We have a different version of rabbit mq installed in another environment and when I see the logs there I see the same error logged as warning. This is also surprising.

Any clue as to how to stop this error? Anything getting logged as Error will raise eyebrows. So trying to find the solution.

Comment: This is just a list a references of sources for people encountering the same issue, unfortunately not directly helping Abi P. Issue 97 on the RabbitMq Got: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management-agent/issues/97 referring to issue 90: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management-agent/issues/90. And a Google.Groups-discussion for rabbit-MQ-users: https://groups.google.com/g/rabbitmq-users/c/9X7g6Z15T-E.